# Interacting with already deployed contracts on brownie framework

Tags: solidity, brownie

Just thought I would put this here for anyone with a similar issue to me.

I had deployed a contract on the seplia testnet in brownie, but could not figure out how to interact with my already-deployed contract. Reading through the docs seemed to confuse me further, but I figured it out in a bit.

When you deploy a contract locally, then disconnect from the network, the contract address is still stored in some sort of 'cahce' in brownie. You have to create a contract object to get its methods attached to the contract.

Example:
`def interact(): x = Contract("CONTRACT ADDRESS DEPLOYED AT ON SEPOLIA") y = x.getBalance("<PARAM>") print(y)`

I was able to fix this issue and hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for reading a already deployed contract is like this

```py
from brownie import <Contract name>

contract = Contract.at(<address>)
[..]
```